# SQL Server functional equivalent to PostgreSQL "in"

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

In postgres you can do a comparison against multiple items like so:

```
 SELECT 'test' IN ('not','in','here');
```

Which is the same as doing:

```
  SELECT ('test' = 'not' OR 'test' = 'in' OR 'test' = 'here');
```

Is there a functional equivalent for SQL Server ?

Comment: What version of MSSQL are you looking for here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is supported, but you will need to put the expression somewhere that accepts a boolean expression. For example, in a `case` statement:

```
select  case  when 'test' in ('not','in','here')  then 1  else 0  end

----------- 
0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Or a `where` clause:

```
select * from T where C in (1,3,5,7,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should give similar results in all recent versions of MSSQL.  You could also write a scalar function to shorten things up a bit.

```
select case 
        when 'test' IN ('not', 'in', 'here') then 1
            else 0
            end;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give 1 if 'test' is in the comparison set 1 or more times, or 0 if it isn't.

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIT) as IsItHere WHERE 'test' IN('not','in','here')
```

Note that the cast isn't strictly necessary, but may be useful if this is called from another language... It should then resolve to a boolean.

EDIT: According to MSSQL Query planner, this is executed ~4 times faster then the CASE method. YMMV.